# Guild banners and allies

Tags: guild-wars-2

The description for the karma banner states it gives the bonus to any ally touching it. Does it mean guild member or anyone from your world? The name of the "+5% Exp Public Banner" confuses me.

So are all banner world-wide or restricted to guild members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Guild Banners are clickable by anyone in the world and act as advertised.

I say this from personal experience; I once found one at the exit from Rata Sum, which was a pleasant surprise as I went to leave.